# help with jQuery show and delay

Tags: jquery

Essentially I want the text to fadeIn,delay for a 3 seconds and then fadeOut. The following code fades in then out immediately, then wont fade in for 3 seconds.

```
$('#temp').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        $('#temp').html(response);
                    }).fadeOut('slow').delay('3000');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to chain them in the right order:

```
$('#temp').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $('#temp').html(response);
          }).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: `'3000'`? Let's de-stringify that. That looks almost as bad as PHP devs using `"$var"` instead of `$var` ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - oops, missed that, wasn't even looking since the question said the 3 second delay afterwards was happening, good catch